# Site permissions

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions

I was looking for setting more comprehensive permissions than what's available out of the box. I'm looking to set up a group where users have the permissions to create/edit lists, pages, libraries but not create sub sites.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what the default "contribute" level permission set does.  If you lookup the permissions assigned to "contribute" you will notice it does not have the "create sub site" permissions.

Microsoft has ample documentation available via Office.com, Technet, and MSDN on how to do this, along with a ton of 3rd party blog posts when you do a search for "SharePoint Permissions"

Start here for description of the permission items:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721640.aspx

And here for how to configure custom permission sets:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263239.aspx

Rob Finney provides a downloadable spreadsheet showing the defualt permission levels an dpermission sets.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/uksharepoint/archive/2010/10/20/updated-permissions-permissions-spreadsheet-for-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Comment: I new this was a silly question; I really overlooked the contribute permission. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be implemented. In sharepoint, you can set/add permission level. You can also design the permission level. If you want your group to have the permissions to create/edit lists, pages, libraries but not create sub sites, you can do these:

1. Login in sharepoint as administrator or some other user that have sufficient permission
2. Enter Permisison Settings (Site Actions - Site Permissions), then click Permission Levels - Add a permission level (in this example, the permission level named "PL1")
3. Select all except Create Subsites in Site Permissions
4. Grant permision "PL1" for your desired group

By these you can implement what you want.